# How to deploy a react, strapi app on heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, strapi

I'm creating a an app using react as the frontend and strapi as the backend with a mongobd database.

So I have two folders at the root of the app `client` and `server`

Is it possible to deploy both folders like this on heroku.

I have read in another tutorial that

> If deploying your backend to a provider that does not persist storage
> on the server like Heroku, the default Strapi local server upload will
> not work as your files on the server are automatically wiped
> periodically.

Just trying to find the best way to deploy this app

Answer (score 0):

It just so happens that I just build a project like this. For the frontend I used Gatsby and Strapi for the CMS. I deployed the Strapi app on Heroku (and used a Postgresql database - you can add this as a plugin from the Heroku dashboard, or do the same with MongoDB) and the Gatsby app on Netlify (same thing you can do with a React app).

It's true that by default Heroku wipes your data once a day (I think), but since are connecting your app to Mongo that shouldn't be an issue. Just add the DB variables to the respective fields in your Heroku app's dashboard.

I like to keep the front and backend separate myself, so I would deploy them as separate repos, either on Heroku or anywhere else.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).